# Sending an email from python (purchased from wix)

Tags: python, django, email

A client of mine has recently decided to get his domain and email packages from Wix, and then decided to use that domain with a Django/python application. I cannot find a quick way to send an email using a python script, I have tried to use the same gmail settings to no avail.

Is there a tutorial somewhere that I can follow? has anyone accomplished that before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out Wix email is part of G suite and all I needed was to switch the less secure access on from the G suit control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Using django:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

Note that you have to configure some properties like **EMAIL_HOST**, **EMAIL_PORT**, etc. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/) you have the docs.